# Create more Elements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reactive-programming, createelement

I need to pass more than 1  element as  argument in my function, here it is how I am doing with only 1 element

`var first = require('./First’)`

How can I pass more elements as argument here? For example with also

```
var second = require(‘./Second’)
```

Here the code example

```
var fs = require('fs')
var React = require('react')
var ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server')
var First = require('./First')
var Second = require('./Second')

var build = function(name, props) {

  var svg =  ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(React.createElement(First, props))

  fs.writeFileSync('client/data/' + name + '.svg', svg)

}

build(‘my-icon', {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ES5**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
var Manna = require('./Manna');
var Cog = require('./Cog');

var build = function(name, props) {

    var size = props.size || 64;

    var svgProps={
        xmlns:"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
        viewBox:[0, 0, size, size].join(' '),
        width:size,
        height:size
    };

    var svg = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
        React.createElement("svg",svgProps,
        React.createElement(Cog,props),
        React.createElement(Manna,props))
    );

    fs.writeFileSync('client/data/' + name + '.svg', svg);

};

build('manna-icon', {});
```

**ES6 JSX and BABEL**

```
import fs from 'fs';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from 'react-dom/server';
import Manna from './Manna';
import Cog from './Manna';

const build = (name="defaultName", props)=> {
    let size = props.size || 64;

    let svgProps={
        xmlns:"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
        viewBox:`0 0 ${size} ${size}`,
        width:size,
        height:size
    };

    let svg = renderToStaticMarkup(
    <svg {...svgProps}>
       <Cog {...props}/> 
       <Manna {...props}/>
    </svg>);

    fs.writeFileSync(`client/data/${name}.svg`, svg);
};

build('manna-icon', {});
```

for jsx and es6 features you need for instance [babel-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-cli)

```
npm install -D babel-cli nodemon
```

then in package.json

```
{...
"scripts":{
     "start":"nodemon --exec babel-node server.js"
       }
...
}
```

[video tutorial babel-node](https://egghead.io/lessons/node-js-using-es6-and-beyond-with-node-js#/tab-transcript)  |  [more about jsx](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

Comment: thanks, but i have also figured it out like this https://gist.github.com/Mannaio/3da1751a4270f048a0ab81899a8afa64 but i am sure it is not the best way. Thanks for your answer , i do not need a wrapper div, if you want to correct me the gist i accept yoiur answer

Comment: @Koala7 Ok , i have edited with svg tag https://gist.github.com/umbertoo/6f2cfae2f19c5d0e5c79959b35b3f931

Comment: @Koala also es6 variant in gist's comment